# hibernate mapping list-index

Tags: hibernate

I am using list for one-to-many bi-directional mapping in hibernate..

following is my code for list:

```
<list name="fEvents" table="FTP_SCAN_EVENTS" cascade="save-update" access="field">
  <key column="LOCATION_ID"  />
  <list-index column="idx" />
  <one-to-many class="FtpScanEvents" />
</list>
```

the `column idx` in the table is not generating..Do I have to have it as a property in my class? any suggestion on generating this Id...?

Comment: What do you mean by not generated. Hbm2ddl or populated with value

Comment: idx column in the table is getting default value as '0'..

Comment: do I need to check for a condition to increment the idx values or how is it going to insert 1 or 2 if there is already a 0

Comment: What is your collection class

Comment: And also add scenario code. New or update ...

Comment: using List..when I add a new row to the table, depedning on one of the column(locationId) i should either increment the idx value or keep it as default..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to chnage to index instead of list-index.
You dont need property for the index.
Hibernate calc it based on position in the list. You can also define base to start the position from another base than 0

In addtional check this - [Bidirectional list](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: i was thinking to use bag instead of list..if I use bag...was it going to be same as list to iterate through the bag ans display it in the jsp

Comment: from the java prespective list can mapped either to list or bag. bag is unordered list , means that the position of the list will not be saved in the database , so loading from the database will not always give you the same order as was in the list. you can use bag with order attribute that will tell hibernate how to place them in the list , so you will have the business order that you want. from iteration they are the same - java list in both cases